# dynamic query generated by stored procedure or function

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a grid with 4 columns i.e title, description, keyword, date in C#.net
with search button and textbox.

When I write title+description+keyword+date it will return the related data by clicking search button.

If I write keyword+date +keeping description and title null it will return related data from grid. And so on other combination's of this 4 column.

That is, it's searching from fields in each column and combination changes dynamically

I want a stored procedure or function for it in SQL SERVER. Any suggestion?.. thanks in advance

Comment: Did you get your problem solved? If yes then mark any of the answers as accepted if you find it really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a procedure with four parameters (each for your options) and following SQL

```
CREATE PROC Search(
  @title VARCHAR(20) NULL, ...
AS SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE (title = @title OR @title IS NULL) etc.
```

Anyway, you should parse the input to get values for each parameter. So when you pass null to @title parameter the WHERE condition `(title = @title OR @title IS NULL)`
 will be always true.

Comment: i m trying to create procedure but problem is how to combine these 4 parameter as it will be desired on runtime which combination of parameter user want to search

Comment: does it mean that you don't know how the user fills in the input field? can you send an example of user input?

Comment: i  got my problem solved.. I m new to this page so wasn't allow to post the screen for my requirement.... thank u for help...

Answer (score 0):

Make a function in C#, pass it string array containing column names and table name, this function will return the query string.

```
public string BuildQuery(string[] columnNames, string tableName)
{
string query = string.Empty;

query = "SELECT ";
foreach(string str in columnNames)
query += str + ", ";
query = query.Substring(0, query.Length - 1);
query += " FROM " + tableName;

return query;
}
```